# Custom property names

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create a function like this:

```
hello({ x: "hello", y: "world" })
```

And want to have TypeScript understanding that this is valid:

```
const greeting = hello({ x: "hello", y: "world" })

greeting.x
greeting.y
```

But this is not:

```js
// ...

greeting.z
```

I'm pretty sure that this might be answered somewhere in the webs, but can't figure an appropriate keyword to research properly—that's why I am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with generics, telling TypeScript that the shape of what it returns is the same as the shape of what it receives:

```
function hello<T>(obj: T): T {
//            ^^^----^^^-^^^------------------------------------ ***
    return /*...an object with the same shape as `obj`...*/;
}
```

Using it is exactly as shown in your question.

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wDwBUB8AFHAEYBWAXIrgJRW6IDeAUIm4gE6pQgdKlkA3MwC+zCAgDOURAHMu3GGFmIAvCgxZCjRAA8qAIjSY4BgDSIAnoYDucDugAmBxCJrNxUuOlQA6LLKE8qiKyr66NMISYJLefgFBCrBhlpFAA)

Comment: Hey T.J.! Thank you for your quick answer!

Let me know something that might be unrelated (actually, it is), but what if I want "hello" and "world" to be the property names? I mean, the values of the properties instead of having "x" and "y"?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - I don't *think* TypeScript does that, but I'm not sure. (I'm sure it doesn't if you aren't passing an object *literal* into `hello`. But if you are, I don't know, sorry.)